# How to manipulate data.frame object in different list more elegantly?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have data.frame objects in the list which is the output of my function I implemented. However, I intend to make new list where data.frame object in different list put it together. I tried several way to get my expected output but not much elegant. Does anyone know any useful trick of doing this manipulation efficiently ? Is there any elegant solution to accomplish this task ? Any idea?

This is mini example:

```
savedList <- list(
  foo_saved = data.frame(v1=c(1,6,16), v2=c(4,12,23)),
  bar_saved = data.frame(v1=c(7,19,31), v2=c(16,28,41)),
  cat_saved = data.frame(v1=c(5,13,26), v2=c(11,21,42))
)

dropedList <- list(
  foo_droped = data.frame(v1=c(4,9,20), v2=c(7,15,29)),
  bar_droped = data.frame(v1=c(14,26,35), v2=c(21,30,47)),
  cat_droped = data.frame(v1=c(18,29,39), v2=c(25,36,48))
)
```

This is my expected output:

```
foo <- list(
  foo_saved = data.frame(v1=c(1,6,16), v2=c(4,12,23)),
  foo_droped = data.frame(v1=c(4,9,20), v2=c(7,15,29))
)

bar <- list(
  bar_saved = data.frame(v1=c(7,19,31), v2=c(16,28,41)),
  bar_droped = data.frame(v1=c(14,26,35), v2=c(21,30,47))
)

cat <- list(
  cat_saved = data.frame(v1=c(5,13,26), v2=c(11,21,42)),
  cat_droped = data.frame(v1=c(18,29,39), v2=c(25,36,48))

)
```

I tried some existing solution but I am not feeling satisfy with it. How can I get my desired output easily ? Is there any efficient, compatible solution for this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: `purrr::transpose(list(saved=savedList, droped=dropedList))` might be an option.

Comment: @lukeA: Thanks, this one also works nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the two lists, then split on the common part of the names. `split()` is not the most efficient function ever, but the code for this is very simple.

```
x <- c(savedList, dropedList)
split(x, sub("_.*", "", names(x)))
```

This gives the following:

```
List of 3
 $ bar:List of 2
  ..$ bar_saved :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 7 19 31
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 16 28 41
  ..$ bar_droped:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 14 26 35
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 21 30 47
 $ cat:List of 2
  ..$ cat_saved :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 5 13 26
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 11 21 42
  ..$ cat_droped:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 18 29 39
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 25 36 48
 $ foo:List of 2
  ..$ foo_saved :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 1 6 16
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 4 12 23
  ..$ foo_droped:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 4 9 20
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 7 15 29
```

Comment: I know you'll hate it, but this pipes nicely: `c(savedList, dropedList) %>% split(substr(names(.), 1, 3))`

Comment: I personally not much like to do merging list and group them. Your solution is interesting, I'll give it try.

Comment: @Andy.Jian - `split(x, sub("_.*", "", names(x)))[c("foo", "bar", "cat")]`?

Comment: If you're ordering based on the names in the original lists, you could use `[sub("_.*", "", names(savedList))]` in place of `[c("foo", "bar", "cat")]` above

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Thanks your big help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mapply` for this, it will iterate thru both lists and make a list with each pair of items:

```
res <- mapply( list, savedList, dropedList, SIMPLIFY = F)
str(res)
List of 3
 $ foo_saved:List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 1 6 16
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 4 12 23
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 4 9 20
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 7 15 29
 $ bar_saved:List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 7 19 31
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 16 28 41
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 14 26 35
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 21 30 47
 $ cat_saved:List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 5 13 26
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 11 21 42
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ v1: num [1:3] 18 29 39
  .. ..$ v2: num [1:3] 25 36 48
```

Comment: `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` is `Map`.

Comment: Thanks. new obtained list become nested list now, How can I get out nested list instead ? I am interesting to do further manipulation for each sublist ? Any idea ?

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution is dependent on the elements being in one-to-one order across the two lists.

Comment: Yes, this one is good. Thanks your help. I rather accept to use Rich' solution.